# SSL session resumption in JBoss

Tags: ssl, jboss

I'm trying to add SSL session resumption to my project.
Is there some settings in Jboss 6 that I have to turn on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java JSSE already supports SSL session resumption. Unless JBoss supplies its own SSL, which isn't likely, there is nothing you need to do.

Comment: what does this mean? what have i todo, that it is SSL only? I have a selfsigned SSL certificate - where is the place to copy it and what i have to do in the pom.xml / web.xml / server.xml?? thx

Comment: @Joerg I've answered your question. I don't know what 'that it is SSL only?' means. Your other questions are new questions unrelated to SSL session resumption, and should be asked in a new thread.